# PHP - Imagick bad pdf quality

Tags: php, pdf, imagick, image-compression

I'm trying to convert a pdf file's 1st page to jpeg. Even I don't use compression, I get a very bad quality image. This is the code I use:

```
<?php
$im = new Imagick("filename.pdf[0]");
$im->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG); 
$im->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');

$im->writeImage('filename.jpg');
$im->clear(); 
$im->destroy();
echo "<img style=\"border:0.5px solid black;\" src=\"filename.jpg\">";
?>
```

1st is the original pdf, 2nd is the converted image:
[image: Original]
[image: Converted]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set image resolution.

try this :

```
<?php 

    $im = new Imagick();
    $im->setResolution(250, 250);
    $im->readImage("filename.pdf[0]") ;
    $im->setImageResolution(250, 250);
    $im->flattenImages();
    $im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
    $im->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
    $im->setImageCompressionQuality(100);

    # Combine multiple images into one, stacked vertically.
    # In case you have multiple pdf pages.
    //$im->resetIterator();
    //$im = $imagick->appendImages(true);


    $im->writeImage('filename.jpg');
    $im->clear(); 
    $im->destroy();
    
    echo "<img style=\"border:0.5px solid black;\" src=\"filename.jpg\">";

?>
```